# Suppose that a is a group element and $a^6 = e$. What are the possibilities for $|a|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose that $a$ is a group element and $a^6 = e$. What are the possibilities for $|a|$? (Gallian, *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, Exercise 18, Chapter 3.)

I just started looking at Abstract Algebra again and I was stuck on this question. It will probably be extremely simple for all of you but I didn't know what to do.

I tried doing regular operations like those found in arithmetic but obviously, that is one of the reasons why Abstract Algebra is so difficult.

Comment: To make your intuition rigorous you might try to prove the following theorem: If $a^n = e$ then $|a|$ divides $n$. As a hint, use the definition of order of an element and any relevant ideas from number theory that involve divisibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does $|a|$ mean?  It is the order of $a$.  This is defined to be

> the smallest positive number $n$ for which $a^n = e$.

But you know that $a^6 = e$.  So whatever $|a|$ is, it is a positive number that is not more than 6. That narrows down the possibilities considerably.  Can you proceed from there?

Comment: So then, by intuition, the answers must be 1,2,3, and 6.

Comment: Usually we like to have an answer that is better than intuition, which is notoriously unreliable. You should have an unassailable argument about why it couldn't be 4.  Why couldn't it be 4?

Comment: Becauase 6/4 is not an integer.

Comment: So what? Couldn't you have $a^4=e$ and also $a^6 = e$?

Comment: It's not in set N

Comment: Who said anything about $6/4$?  Why is it relevant?

Comment: And that is where my illiteracy of the subject now comes into play.

Comment: Well, perhaps you could think about it a little more and try to figure it out. What would happen if you had both $a^4=e$ and $a^6 = e$?

Comment: Then a = 1 or 0?

Comment: @Matthew if the order of $a$ is $4$ then $a^4=e$.   So $a^5 = e\cdot a$. Then $a^6= e\cdot a \cdot a = a^2 \ne a$ as $4$ is the smallest $n$ such that $a^n = e$

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn’t it just be the divisors of 6?

For instance, if $|a| = 2$, then $a^6$ would be $e$, in virtue of:

> $a^6 = (a^2.a^2).a^2 = (e.e).e = e.e = e$

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Thanks for being patient with me. Looks like there are a lot of talented professionals here.

Comment: No problem.  My group theory has been rusting for 20 years.  So, not even basics are obvious to me anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is |a| = 1,2,3,6**

**Reason**

Let S = {n $\in \mathbb{Z} : n>0$}. Let m be the smallest element in S such that $a^m = e$ of $|a|=e$.
But we know that $a^6=e$. Now, from Corollary 2 of Theorem 4.1 (Gallian, Contemporary Abstract Algebra.) m divides 6.
Therefore (from number theory) 6=qm+r where $0 \leq r <m$ where $q \; and \;  r \in S$. This implies, $r= 6 - qm$. Now, $a^r=a^6 -a^{qm} \implies a^r =e$. This contradicts the assumption that m is the smallest element of S such that $a^m=e$. Thus $r=0$. Thus qm=6.Thus m is a positive integer less than or equal to 6 which divides 6 without leaving a remainder. Hence m=1,2,3,6.

I would appreciate any suggestions for improvement in my answer.
Thank You!